# Composer not generating autoload files package made by me

Tags: php, composer-php

I hate to add more to the noise of "autoload isn't working!!!!!", but I can't seem to get this problem figured out, and I figured getting some fresh eyes on it would get the problem in a lot less time. Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'model/PageNav.php';

use ShinePHP\{Crud, CrudException, EasyHttp, EasyHttpException, HandleData, HandleDataException};

// ALWAYS serve over encrypted channels
try {
    EasyHttp::checkHttps();
} catch (EasyHttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}


try {

    // check if it's a GET request, if it is, serve page, if not, do nothing
    if (EasyHttp::isRequestMethod('GET')) {
        $Page = new PageNav('Home', 'view/home.php');
        $Page->buildPage();
        exit;
    }

} 
catch (EasyHttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

So obviously I am using a package from composer called ShinePHP (it's one I've made, and I'm still working on the documentation, so I'm just using it for my own projects at the moment, composer just makes package management so easy!) 
ANYWAYS...because I'm writing this question, I'm obviously getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ShinePHP\EasyHttp' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/KRTY/src/index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/KRTY/src/index.php on line 11
```

Now, I haven't manually touched the composer.json file, so here it is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "adammcgurk/shine-php": "~0.0.1"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ShinePHP\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors on requiring the `vendor/autoload.php` file (and I've tried changing the path to something that doesn't exist like `vendor/alkdjfladksf/autoload.php` and it throws an error how it should), I'm running PHP version 7.2.7 on XAMPP on Mac OS Mojave. Here is the directory structure, the highlighted index.php file is the one with the code above:
[image]

And here is the output of `composer dump-autoload -o`:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
```

And so...to add more to the fire of this question on Stack...**How can I get composer to autoload my ShinePHP namespace with the classes as shown in the code?**

Comment: You don't have any [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) information in your [composer.json](https://github.com/ShineSolar/ShinePHP/blob/master/composer.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dependency [does not have any autoloading rules](https://github.com/ShineSolar/ShinePHP/blob/0.0.1/composer.json), so Composer does not know where to find `ShinePHP\EasyHttp` class. You need to add autoloading configuration in `composer.json` of `shine-php` package:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "ShinePHP\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

Comment: So I added that code to my composer file (the full composer.json is edited above), but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @AdamMcGurk You have to bump the version number.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, I added that to my package and I'm all good now. Thanks for the tip @Sammitch, because I did have to bump my version number